# Play framework: Edit welcome tag

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am Play framework beginner!.  started play version 1.2.5.

i am following getting started guide 
[here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1/firstapp)

When i see `helloworld/app/views/Application/index` file i see the tag

```
#{welcome /}
```

which produces welcome screen content .

now i need to change the content of that tag..

where i need to edit the tag content .? please help me!

Comment: Just curious: why Play 1.x when current stable version is 2.2.x ?

Comment: because i have joined a project which is already using 1.2.5 :)

Comment: The only reason anyone uses Play 1 these days is because their workplace/group has a legacy app to support. ... yeah, what he just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the content of the tag.  It's just a convenience thing to auto-generate a welcome message.  You can remove it and replace it with:

```
<h2>See, I changed the tag!</h2>
```

Here's the whole index.html, modified:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

<h2>See, I changed the tag!</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags in Play framework are usually in

```
app/views/tags
```

folder. This one has to be called `welcome.html`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no welcome.html in the project,
maybe you can try to find the welcome.html in the folder where the play framework is installed.
And the path maybe like xxxxx\play-1.3.3\framework\templates\tags.